# how to pass the input query parameters when calling an endpoint using toD/to uri in XML DSL of apache camel version 3.20.x

Tags: apache-camel, stack-overflow, apache-camel-k, xml-dsl

Can someone help me on how to pass the input query parameters when calling an endpoint using toD/to uri in XML DSL of apache camel version 3.20.x.

I am trying this way. Can someone help me with this.

<toD uri = rest:get:api/v1/xyz?queryParamA=${header.parameter1}&queryParamB=${header.parameter2} />

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: According to the documentation [1], that's the right way to do that. Mind that you need to wrap the content in quotes, though.

[1] https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/eips/toD-eip.html#_using_tod